# Can you stop the main function from running from an internal function

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a project to wirelessly control my neo-pixel lights. I have an infinite loop in one of my functions to create a rainbow effect. The only problem is when the next function needs to be called (i.e to turn off the lights) the program won't stop looping through the first loop. I was wondering is it was possible to stop a function from running via an internal function and if it was how to go about doing it. I would appreciate any help anyone could give me.

Thanks in advance,
Henry G

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
import board
import neopixel
import time

# Choose an open pin connected to the Data In of the NeoPixel strip, i.e. board.D18
pixel_pin = board.D18

# The number of LEDs
num_pixels = 20

# The order of the LED colors - RGB or GRB. Some LED Strips - like ours - have red and green reversed!
ORDER = neopixel.GRB

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, num_pixels, brightness=0.7, auto_write=False, pixel_order=ORDER)

app = Flask(__name__)

rainOn = False
triggered = False
go = False

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world'

@app.route('/rgb/<r>/<g>/<b>')
def color(r, g, b):
    global go
    go = False
    global pixels
    pixels.fill((int(r), int(g), int(b)))
    pixels.show()
    return 'The color you have chosen is now showing!'

@app.route('/off')
def off():
    global go
    global rainOn
    rainOn = False
    go = False
    global pixels
    pixels.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pixels.show()
    return 'The lights are now off!'

@app.route('/rainbow')
def rainbow():
    global go
    global triggered
    global rainOn
    rainOn = True
    triggered = True
    go = True
    while go == True:
            def end():
                go = False
                return
            def wheel(pos):
                if pos < 0 or pos > 255:
                    r = g = b = 0
                elif pos < 85:
                    r = int(pos * 3)
                    g = int(255 - pos*3)
                    b = 0
                elif pos < 170:
                    pos -= 85
                    r = int(255 - pos*3)
                    g = 0
                    b = int(pos*3)
                else:
                    pos -= 170
                    r = 0
                    g = int(pos*3)
                    b = int(255 - pos*3)
                return (r, g, b) if ORDER == neopixel.RGB or ORDER == neopixel.GRB else (r, g, b, 0)
            def rainbow_cycle(wait):
                global rainOn
                global triggered
                global go
                if go == True and triggered == True and rainOn == True:
                    for j in range(255 ** 255):
                        for i in range(num_pixels):
                            pixel_index = (i * 256 // num_pixels) + j
                            pixels[i] = wheel(pixel_index & 255)
                        pixels.show()
                        time.sleep(wait)
                elif go == False or triggered == False or rainOn == False:
                    end()

            while rainOn == True and triggered == True and go == True:

                rainbow_cycle(0.0035)
                return 'Rainbow off'
    return 'Done'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind having rainbow_cycle() as a nested function?

Comment: There is no real reason apart from organisation. rainbow_cycle(), as well as wheel() could both be modified to be out of the main function. As for end() that was mainly me just experimenting to see if I could get rainbow() as a whole to stop.

Comment: In general, global variables/functions are highly discouraged. One of the reasons is because you could be accedently changing it somewhere causing something else to break, an infinite loop in your case. My recomendation is to change your globals to locals, and perhaps split apart the nested functions. I'll create an actual answer on here later today if anyone else hasnt gotten to it.